# Differences between BufferedImage pixels and Color.getRGB() pixels

Tags: java, arrays, colors, bufferedimage, pixel

I'm trying to get pixel data from a bufferedimage that will only contain a gray scale translucent image (argb).
I'm getting a WritableRaster from the image and setting its pixels using the Raster's setPixels method.
using this method, I get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exceptions. After doing some research, i found that BufferedImages store one integer per pixel per band instead of having one integer per pixel. That is, 8 bits for each band for each pixel.
This causes me a ton of trouble as i try to access and change the types of colors.
I'm at a loss.
I'll post any other details if need be.
Thank you,
Sina

Comment: @user2511414 He didn't say it.

Comment: I'd say your more likely writing beyond the pixel buffer (width/height) of the image

Comment: Ultimately, i'm trying to manipulate individual pixels of a bufferedimage. The problem is getRGB and setRGB are painfully slow and the bufferedimage does not give me access to an integer array that isn't of size width * height * number_of_bands.
I want an array of size width * height with each of the 4 bands being stored in 8 bits of the 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would you please share the code? you have to note that if you want to set a rectangle (128x128) on part of an image, you have to call the set RGB method like this

```
//start points to draw
int blockX=128,blockY=128;
//size of the target rectangle need to be painted
int w=128,h=128;
int[] colors=new int[h*w];
//....init color array
//start painting from x value in array
int colorOffset=0;
//number of value should read from array for one row
int paintWidth=128;
//I think you get the Exception here, because of wrong number passed for drawing pixel for each row
out.setRGB(blockX,blockY, w, h, colors, colorOffset, paintWidth);
```

once again, we are not magician, please share the code buddy :)
[this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616115/Java-Thread-Example#rccig) also would help you